# Laravel how to pass parameters to controller middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do something but i cant even imagine how to do it.

To pass parameters to a middlware I'm doing this:

```
Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'role:editor', function ($id) {
    //
}]);
```

From the laravel documentation.
Then get the parameter in the handle function...

But laravel suggest to declare the middleware use in the __construct in the Controller, insted in the route.

So...

```
public function __construct() {
       $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

But i dont know how to pass parameters to the Controller.

I would thank any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can access url parameters into middleware shown as below:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/test/{id}', ['uses' => 'Test@test']);
```

**Test Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Test extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Test constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('test');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return 'sample';
    }
```

**Test Middleware**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Test
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request->id);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

** dont forget update your Kernel.php to activate middleware

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'test' => \App\Http\Middleware\Test::class,
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

@muhammad-sumon-molla-selim answer is actually the best one according to the question, but it leaks into explanation.

With my knowledge I was able to follow his guideline so here is a full example plus a usecase where Route's middleware or Request parameters is not possible.

I have an abstract CRUDControllerBase, which is extended by many child controllers.
Each child controllers need a different permission to perform any action on the model excepts index/show.

So I was forced to dynamically pass the permission (string) from the controller to the Middleware, here is the base structure:

```php
// App\Http\Controllers\CRUDControllerBase.php
abstract class CRUDControllerBase extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string The needed permission to call store or update
     * If null, permission is granted to every users
     */
    protected ?string $permission = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Here I need to pass to VerifyUserPermission the controller's permission
        $this->middleware(VerifyUserPermission::class)
             ->except(['index', 'show']);
    }
}

// App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController.php
class DocumentController extends CRUDControllerBase
{
    protected ?string $permission = 'documents';
}

// App\Http\Controllers\EventController.php
class EventController extends CRUDControllerBase
{
    protected ?string $permission = 'events';
}
```

And here is how I tackled this following the @muhammad-sumon-molla-selim answer:

```php
// App\Http\Middleware\VerifyUserPermission.php
// Create the VerifyUserPermission middleware, which accepts the permission string
class VerifyUserPermission
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ?string $permission): mixed
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        // If a permission is needed but the user doesn't have it, abort
        if ($permission && !$user->$permissionField) {
            abort(401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

// App\Http\Kernel.php
// Register the middleware
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        // [...]
        'permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyUserPermission::class
    ];
}

// App\Http\Controllers\CRUDControllerBase.php
// Then just register the middleware into the CRUDControllerBase's constructor
abstract class CRUDControllerBase extends Controller
{
    protected ?string $permission = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // 'documents' permission will be needed for Documents' edition
        // 'events' permission will be needed for Events' edition
        // And so on for many others controllers
        $this->middleware("permission:$this->permission")
             ->except(['index', 'show']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant understand it. 
I dont know where is the "role" coming from?
"role" is not on the route.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the middleware in the controller. Keep business logic out of the controller as often as possible.

Instead, make your middleware file.

```
php artisan make:middleware MyMiddlewareDoesThings
```

Now inside of your file, locate the `$handle` function.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
```

Just add arguments after the request and closure

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
```

Now `$role` will contain the value of `role:value` which from your example would be `$editor`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, with this :

```
Route::get('post/{id}', function () {
    // Your controller method here
})->middleware('myMiddleware');
```

And in the middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class MyMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $id = $request->route('id');

        // Your middleware logic here

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get the parameters in the __construct of your controller you could do this:

```
class HomeController extends \BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->routeParamters = Route::current()->parameters();
    }
}
```

Comment: He had asked about how to pass parameter when calling middleware from controller, not to get the parameters.

Comment: The question is about passing parameters to middleware.

Comment: then please check this ,  https://mattstauffer.co/blog/passing-parameters-to-middleware-in-laravel-5.1

Comment: also check , https://ahesanalisuthar.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/laravel-5-1-pass-middleware-parameters-as-array/   I think this will solve your problem